Cant draw anything on canvas using surfaceView?
I can't get anything to show up on screen. I have created a Empty Views Action then written the following code. (Copied from youtube where it works)
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Paint redpaint = new Paint();
    public GamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        redpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawRect(50,50,100,100,redpaint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}

I have checked all kinds of things:

I have changed the background color to make sure I can see the view
I have checked that c (the canvas from lockCanvas()) is not null
I have checked that visibility for this and parent is 0

And all other kinds of checks that ChatGPT said I should do
I have now narrowed the problem down to the emulator. I tried connecting my phone which seemed to fix the problem. However, since I would like to use the emulator this still poses a problem.
The emulator seems to be working fine but whatever I draw to the screen never shows up.

The code seems OK. Can you verify that the activity is created? What do you see when it starts?

When it starts it is just black. However if I add this
setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
in the surfaceView constructor the screen is white instead of black.

Can you try to move the line redpaint.setColor(Color.RED) before the line getHolder().addCallback(this)?
